# hlookup vlookup return more than one value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to modify `hlookup` and `vlookup` so it can return average of 3 values rather than 1 single value? Let's say originally it can return the value from cell "F4", but now the idea is to return with the average of "D4", "E4", "F4" from the target worksheet. Thanks for any help in advance!

Data:

[image: data]

Main:

[image: main]

(input is "date" in main worksheet)

Comment: Are you looking for `AVERAGEIF`?

Comment: probably not, the way it works is that I input a date and it returns with the average of salary from 3 month prior to input. the data are from a different worksheet so I guess I have to use the lookup function

Comment: Actually that sounds like the exact use case for `AVERAGEIF`, or maybe `AVERAGEIFS`. Can you provide some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: uploaded, thanks for the help

Comment: Do you mean "but now the idea is to return with the average of "D4", "E4", "F4"  from the _Data_ worksheet"?

Comment: my bad. yes....